# cordova-network-information with latest cordova version error

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I was using this plugin with cordova 5.4.0 version and it was OK.

Yesterday, I updated to cordova 6 and now this plugin doesn't work anymore.
If I include the plugin, the app doesn't work and the log shows

```
cordova.js:1223 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
cordova.js:1216 Channel not fired: onCordovaConnectionReady
cordova.js:1216 Channel not fired: onCordovaInfoReady
```

If I take it out, the app work OK but I need this plugin...

Do you have any ideas how can I fix this???

Comment: Hi, have you updated all plugins you have as well?

Comment: yes I have.....

Comment: No sure if it'll help but what I've done was to reduce loading time by 
1. use requirejs 2. minimize plugin usage when app starts 3. use dynamic way of loading pages 4. redirect index.html by using 'window.location'.
Then my problem was gone.